# function not returning a value for no rows returned

Tags: oracle, plsql

I created a function that takes a movie id as input and returns stock information based from the ID. The function mostly works but if I want to retrieve information from a movie that is not in the database(returns no rows) nothing returns. Can't figure out why?

doesn't give me an error when i call an ID that returns no rows so exception handling wouldn't work.

```
create or replace function stock_info 
    (p_id IN NUMBER
    )
return VARCHAR2
IS 
    cursor c1 is 
        select movie_id, movie_title, movie_qty
        from mm_movie
        where p_id = movie_id;
    lv_movie_info VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN

    for i in c1 loop
        if p_id = i.movie_id then 
            lv_movie_info := i.movie_title || ' is available: ' || i.movie_qty || ' on the shelf';
        else
            lv_movie_info := 'no data found';
        end if;
    end loop;

    return lv_movie_info;   
END STOCK_INFO;
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the cursor statement you used fetches data from the in parameter. i.e., in the cursor select you limiting based on the movie id passed.

on passing a movie id which is not in the data base, the cursor select statement would not fetch any records, and so the flow won't even go inside the for loop.

if you wanted to return no data found - on passing a movie id which is not in the database, two ways to resolve
 1. before the loop, have select statement to set a flag to Y or N if exists according and to have your requirement.
2. in if not using for cursor, there is an option to check not found...
sample:

```
declare
cursor c1 is select * from table_sample; -- empty table
c_rec c1%rowtype;
begin
open c1;
fetch c1 into c_rec;
  if c1%notfound then
      dbms_output.put_line('not found');
   end if;
close c1;
end;

-- output
not found
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you don't get anything when there is no data is that the loop doesn't execute. Logically the For expression says "execute the following loop for every row returned in the cursor" but there are no rows in the cursor so it never executes the loop. Further the structure actually indicates you are expecting multiple for a given p_id. If that's not the case you can eliminate the cursor all together. Assuming p_id is the primary key you have either 0 or 1 row so:

```
create or replace function stock_info (p_id in number)
return text
is
    lv_movie_info varchar2(100);
begin
    select i.movie_title || ' is available: ' || i.movie_qty || ' on the shelf'
      into lv_movie_info 
      from mm_movie i 
     where p_id = movie_id;

    return lv_movie_info;
exceptions 
   when no_data_found 
   then return 'no data found';
end stock_info;
```

Of course if do expect more that 1 row the cursor is needed, but the IF is not as the were clause guarantees it's true. Still with 0 rows the loop will not be executed so the 'no data found' message needs to go after "End Loop".

Belayer